# How to calculate the area of part of $(S^2,\tilde g)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Under the polar coordinate, the unit sphere is
$$
S^2=\{(\sin\theta\cos\varphi,\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\cos\theta)\in \mathbb R^3:\theta\in[0,\pi],\varphi\in[0,2\pi] \}
$$
the induced metric is
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\
0 &\sin^2\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, consider a part of $S^2$
$$
S=\{(\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi\cos\delta,\sin\varphi\sin\delta)\in \mathbb R^3:\varphi\in[0,\pi], \delta\in[0,K]\}
$$
And consider a non-induced metric, for example,
$$
\tilde g =\begin{pmatrix}
f(\theta,\varphi) &0 \\
0 & h(\theta,\varphi)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, how to calculate the area of $S$ under the metric $\tilde g$ ?

> Rough drawing of $S$.
> [image]

> The $S^2$
> [image]

Comment: Characterization 2 of the Riemannian volume form [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097427/characterizations-of-riemannian-volume-form) may help.